# Can I use craueform flow bundle for multi step forms using multiple entities

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any way to create multi-step forms with multiple entities using `craueformflow` bundle for my Symfony2 project?

Answer (score 1):

I used two entities to create a two step form.

Here is the piece of code what I wrote for my project.

```
$formData['order'] = new Order();
$formData['address'] = new Address();

$flow = $this->get('myCompany.form.flow.createOrder');
$flow->bind($formData);
...
...
```